# How to create a website enabling a new bibliometric approach currently implemented in R?

Tags: python, php, r, web-applications

Basic question from an "enthusiast" with limited knowledge in R and none in web programming.

I have come up with a new bibliometric approach called TeamTree analysis to analyze and visualize the workforce contributing to a research field of interest based on bibliographic information retrieved from a database (PubMed, Web of Science etc.).

For details https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0253847

The steps are essentially:

- Perform a query e.g. PubMed/MEDLINE, download bibliographic records (csv)
- Extract required information: article authors and the year of publication
- Analyse records, visualize and save data

So far, the analysis is implemented using a R script.
See: https://github.com/fw-pfrieger/TeamTree

Note that I had to teach myself R first (thanks to Stackoverflow!). Learning a different language (Python, perl, php, C+ etc.) was out of reach - probably intellectually, certainly time-wise.

My dream is to set up a publicly accessible website allowing anybody interested to perform this kind of analysis.

My **question** is how to get from my R script to a web-application (or ultimately smartphone app etc.) knowing that

1. Users should be able to query a publicly accessible database directly through the website/app (e.g. PubMed/MEDLINE) rather than the clumsy query-download-read csv circus.
2. Future improvements should allow interactive 3D visuals, where users can display specific info.
3. My script (and R altogether?) may not be optimal in terms of speed and may limit future expansions. Thus, expert help may be required to implement the analysis in a different language.

Thanks!

Comment: At a very, very, very high and simple level, you can have a web form that has inputs for your scripts variables, and you can invoke your R script on the server side. In PHP you’d use a function such as `shell_exec`. There’s a whole bunch of things to learn regarding security and data sanitation, but that’s where I’d start. Eventually I’d see if the R code could be ported to a web language, or I’d look into using a task queue where users submit their requests, and then “pick up” their data shortly after.

Comment: @FrankPfrieger Would you consider development of a `shiny` app?

Comment: Thanks! @Chris I start to realize the complexity

Comment: @Ben I thought about Shiny, but I won't be able to develop this myself, it's beyond my capacities - even less so what Chris suggested.

Comment: @FrankPfrieger, I didn’t mean to dismay you! Security is important, but getting something working has to happen, too. Try getting a simple server running, I’m going to assume PHP but pick whatever. Then try getting it to run your script using [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). Then learn a bit about forms on the web, then tie it all together. Slow and steady. Good luck!

Comment: @FrankPfrieger I totally understand. I'm a fan of shiny, and find it helpful to develop interactive web apps from R code. I admit there is a learning curve in understanding reactivity. Anyways...I really am impressed with TeamTree and looked over the plos one paper...great stuff! Have you considered making it a package? If I have time this week, I'd like to delve a bit deeper into what you have so far on github; perhaps that can give me a better sense of how involved it would be to adapt to shiny...

Comment: @Chris no pb, I highly appreciated your comment, it reinforces my feeling that I need help to get this done.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for your comment. I indeed thought about making a package etc. I'd love to do this, but again, I should spend my time doing research rather than coding :-( Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.